# Variables inside nested for loop in Java

Tags: java, for-loop

I have a for loop inside another for loop as follows in Java:

```
for(int i=0; i<8; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<8; j++){
                ...
            }
        }
```

Where the ... is, I want to create a variable ij, i.e. 00, 01, 02, 03...10, 11 etc. up to 77.

How can I create a variable ij?

Comment: This is confusing to me. What exactly are you trying to have here? a String that holds both i and j values, then do it. Something else? then clarify exactly *what* you're trying to do, not *how* you're trying to do it.

Comment: I'll be creating a JButton for each value ij, so I'll need to name each button inside the nested for loop.

Comment: Then you'll want to give us this information from the get-go. No reason to make us guess what you're thinking.

Comment: Is this homework? Of so, please tag it as such.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like this:

```
int ij = 10*i+j;
```

Comment: Yeah, thought there might be cleaner way though

Answer (score 2):

Just create a String

```
String buttonTitle = "" + i + j;
JButton btn = new JButton(buttonTitle);
```

Or alternatively

```
String buttonTitle = String.valueOf(i) + String.valueOf(j);
JButton btn = new JButton(buttonTitle);
```

or, one that I like best, use String.format(...):

```
String buttonTitle = String.format("%d%d", i, j);
JButton btn = new JButton(buttonTitle);
```

i.e.,

```
public class Foo002 {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
         for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            String text = String.format("%d%d", i, j);
            System.out.print(text + " ");
         }
         System.out.println();
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Run it,

```
public class A {

public static void main(String[] args) {
for(int i=0; i<8; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<8; j++){
            int ij = 10*i+j;
            if (ij < 10)
            System.out.println("0" + ij) ;
            else
            System.out.println(ij) ;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Do you want an integer or string result?

Integer:

```
int ij = 10*i+j;
```

String:

```
String ij = String.format("%d%d", i, j);
```

Comment: You can't call methods on primitives in Java. I'm voting to delete this answer as I think that you're confusing this Java question for C#.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels - Yeah, I'm a C# guy who's fiddled a bit with Java.  I didn't know of this restriction.  Thanks for the pickup.